# Как настроить NTLM авторизацию когда сайт хостится на Linux

Tags: c#, linux, веб-программирование, asp.net-core, mvc

Если создать в VisualStudio WebAppication с Windows авторизацией, то в Programm.cs
генерится вот такой код

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Если я запускаю код в Visual Studio то в браузере поднимается окно для ввода пароля от Windows.(или в зависимости от настроек браузера происходит авто авторизация)
Если же я размещаю сайт на Linux, то при обращении к этому сайту с того же самого браузера окно не поднимается а возникает ошибка 401(понятно, что пользователь не авторизован).

Что нужно сделать что бы проходила авторизация?